# How to append one excel file as a sheet onto another excel file in alteryx

Tags: excel, alteryx

so I have about 90 different excel files that are customer reports. I have one generic excel file that's a summary page that I need to insert as a sheet into all of those other excel files. Does anyone have a way to automate this process - I'm generating the sheets through alteryx but open to solutions outside of that platform or maybe there's a simple way to do it through Excel that I'm missing.

Right now, the only option is to open each report and copy over the summary sheet and insert it that way. To do it for 90 sheets would take me over an hour so trying to shorten the time.

Comment: This is very simple. Just loop through all 90 files and copy the sheet from your generic.

Comment: 3 ways you can do this: batch macro, block until done, or call a Python script at the end of your worfklow to copy the sheet